# Images in table in IE 8-10 too big

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem I cannot get solved.

Please take a look at my html and my css. Why are the pictures perfectly responsive in `safari`,`firefox`,`chrome` but aren't in `IE 8` through 10?

html:

```
<table class="my-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="130"><a href="http://www.kc-werbeartikel.com" target="_blank"><img              style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"     src="/images/sponsoren/kuratli.gif" alt="Kuratli Collection" width="100%" height="auto" /></a> </td>
      <td height="130"><a href="http://www.migros.ch" target="_blank"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="/images/sponsoren/Logo_Migros.JPG" alt="Migros" width="100%" height="auto" /></a>  </td>
      <td height="130"><a href="http://www.gartenbau-weber.ch" target="_blank"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="/images/sponsoren/Logo_Webergartenbau.gif" alt="Webergartenbau" width="100%" height="auto" /></a>  </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
table.my-table td {
  width: 33% !important;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd !important;
}

table.my-table {
  width: 100% !important;
  table-layout: fixed !important; 
  border-spacing: 0.5rem !important;
  border-collapse: separate !important;
}
```

I am pretty new to both, `html` and `css`. I'd like to keep the table since it gives me a nice layout, but I am open for everything which solves my problem.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi Mirko, do you need to be using a table?

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. Use tables for tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `height="auto"` is implemented differently in different browsers. Something that can't by relied upon.

If you remove that, though, images might exceed the space meant for them.

Try omitting the `height` attribute, and adding to the css:

```
table.my-table td img{
   max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hey JNF! Thanks, I use the max-width now as well and it the i.e. shows the picture right! Thanks man!